# Flask HTML CSS Bootstrap Navigation Alignment issue

Tags: html, css, flask

so this is what my site currently looks like: [website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZobw.png)

Now, I am trying to get the Login & Sign up buttons on the same line as the rest of the navigation bar. I tried a few things here with no success. Trying to realign text-end to the left, keeping the centering on text-end and using   (Which of course pushed the rest of the navi bar which is not what I want). And I also tried closing the center with  but of course that wouldn't work since it's using a style in the div. I did close the div, but the result is the screenshot I showed.

my html:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<header class="p-3 text-bg-dark">
  <div class="container" style="display: flex;justify-content: center;">
    <div class="d-flex flex-wrap align-items-center justify-content-center justify-content-lg-start">
      <ul class="nav col-12 col-lg-auto me-lg-auto mb-2 justify-content-center mb-md-0">
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('core.home') }}" class="nav-link" style="color: #929292; font-size: 16px !important;">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('core.home') }}" class="nav-link" style="color: #929292; font-size: 16px !important;">API</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('core.home') }}" class="nav-link" style="color: #929292; font-size: 16px !important;">Terms</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('core.home') }}" class="nav-link" style="color: #929292; font-size: 16px !important;">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{ url_for('core.home') }}" class="nav-link" style="color: #929292; font-size: 16px !important;">Settings</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
      <div class="text-end">
        {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
        <a href="{{ url_for('accounts.logout') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger me-2" style="font-size: 16px !important;">Logout</button></a>
        {% else %}
          <a href="{{ url_for('accounts.login') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 16px !important;">Login</button></a>
          &nbsp;
          &nbsp;
          <a href="{{ url_for('accounts.register') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="font-size: 16px !important;">Sign up</button></a>
        {% endif %}
          
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

my bootstrap base.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SMS Simbi</title>
    <!-- meta -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <!-- styles -->
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename="styles.css")}}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
    {% block css %}{% endblock %}
  </head>
  <body>

    {% include "navigation.html" %}

    <div class="container">

      <br>

      <!-- messages -->
      {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
      {% if messages %}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          {% for category, message in messages %}
          <div class="alert alert-{{ category }} alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
           {{message}}
           <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
      </div>
      {% endif %}
      {% endwith %}

      <!-- child template -->
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}

    </div>

    <!-- scripts -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    {% block js %}{% endblock %}

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is set the header element to the height you want, I put 10rem and add the classes: d-flex, justify-content-center and align-items-center:

```
<header
  class="p-3 text-bg-dark d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"
  style="height: 10rem"
>...</header>
```

To center the menu you can set the buttons to absolute and add a 'right' to them:

```
        <div class="position-absolute" style="right: 1.25rem">
            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('accounts.logout') }}"
                ><button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-danger me-2"
                    style="font-size: 16px !important"
                >
                    Logout
                </button></a
            >
            {% else %}
            <a href="{{ url_for('accounts.login') }}"
                ><button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    style="font-size: 16px !important"
                >
                    Login
                </button></a
            >
            &nbsp; &nbsp;
            <a href="{{ url_for('accounts.register') }}"
                ><button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-success"
                    style="font-size: 16px !important"
                >
                    Sign up
                </button></a
            >
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not fix the issue. As it misaligns the Home to Settings navigations. It brings them to the left more, miscentering them. https://prnt.sc/t5COlg_8K7rb

Comment: @bigboss I will change my answer